# CAST is not working in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the StackExchange Data Explorer to calculate the average number of answers for Java questions that are not closed and have an accepted answer:

```
DECLARE @tagId int;

SELECT  @tagId = Id
FROM    Tags         
WHERE   TagName = 'java';

SELECT  CAST(AVG(AnswerCount) as DECIMAL(5,2)) 
FROM    posts p 
JOIN    PostTags pt ON pt.PostId = p.Id
WHERE   pt.TagId = @tagId
    AND     p.PostTypeID = 1
    AND     p.AcceptedAnswerID IS NOT NULL
    AND     p.ClosedDate IS NULL;
```

However, I always get 2 as a result, even so I try to cast the result to a decimal. I also tried to cast first each result and then cast the average again, but still, I get 2 as a result instead 2.29....

What's my error?

Comment: "I also tried to cast first each result" -- That's exactly what you should do, and what works (yes, I tested before commenting). "and then cast the average again" -- That's harmless, and merely rounds the result.

Comment: try avg(cast(answercount) as (decimal(5,2)) the result of avg is the same type as the input answercount= integer so result is an integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the CAST inside the AVG statement like this:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(AnswerCount as DECIMAL(5,2))) 
FROM posts p 
join PostTags pt 
     on pt.PostId = p.Id
WHERE pt.TagId = @tagId
AND p.PostTypeID = 1
AND p.AcceptedAnswerID IS NOT NULL
AND p.ClosedDate IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

`avg` returns the same data type as it receives. So calculating `avg` on `int`s will return an `int` (in your case, 2). Any widening cast done afterwards is meaningless, as the precision is already lost. One way around this is to cast your column to `decimal` before feeding it to the `avg` function:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(AnswerCount) as DECIMAL(5,2)) 
FROM posts p 
JOIN PostTags pt ON pt.PostId = p.Id
WHERE pt.TagId = @tagId
AND p.PostTypeID = 1
AND p.AcceptedAnswerID IS NOT NULL
AND p.ClosedDate IS NULL;
```